# Can anyone search for traps?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, traps

I'm curious as to whether any character can search for traps, or only someone with an ability like the rogue's trapfinding ability.

Comment: Related: [Does finding and removing a trap require one or two find/remove traps rolls?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/12051/2102)

Comment: Actually, that question has no relationship to this one, other than involving traps. Different rules-system entirely.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Any character can search for traps, but only someone with the [Trapfinding](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/rogue.htm#trapfinding) ability can find traps with a DC of higher than 20.

Also pertinent is that only characters with the above special ability can disable magic traps with use of the [disable device](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/disableDevice.htm) skill.

Comment: Actually, only characters with Trapfinding can disable *magic* traps. Normal traps can be disabled without that ability. Spot on about the restrictions on finding them though.

Comment: Good call @BESW

Comment: Actually anyone can disable the trap once its found...they simply have to activate it! (preferably with a stick or other non-living mattter)  seriously, not being a jerk...when we'flve found ourselves short a rogue had to "manually disable" the trap this way...fair warning, its not always as safe as you think ..(guess thats the purpose)

Comment: @Ben-Jamin how about automatic reset traps? There's are of effect too :P

Comment: Usually there's a time limit before it resets..if not well then hopefully u made it past the trap or got w/e u needed alrdy..and btw I'm definitely NOT encouraging this style of "disable" but with no other choices... :)